# Position fixed not working as expected in some browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a small "Feedback" button on the left bottom of a page. It is positioned with `fixed`.

However on some browsers (old versions of webkit mainly) it isn't displayed as expected at the bottom of the page.

Here some screenshots (the error is visible on XP chrome 25, Win 8 firefox 18, Win 7 firefox 3.6, etc.):
http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/0d783c572a3da30c4ad2482b86cdce92dcf0788b

How can I fix this wrong behavior?

I am not interested in overcomplicated solutions like sticky footers, because even if the button hides some text is not a problem.

CSS:

```
#support {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#support a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  ...
}
```

HTML inside many other nested `div`s:

```
<div id="support"><a href="#">…</a></div>
```

Comment: Probably it is a BrowserStack issue, because when I take the screenshots on BrowserStack from pro I get the correct results. I am a little bit confused by this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue related to the way screenshots are taken. The code is correct and the button is positioned correctly in all browsers.